# how to write this query in access 2007

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

```
select ((select SUM (Total) 
           from Shirt_Mes 
           where CustomerId =2 
           and Created_Date ='2016-10-05 05:25:06.000')
      + (select SUM (Total)
           from Pant_Mes 
            where CustomerId =2 
            and Created_Date ='2016-10-05 05:25:06.000' )
```

Comment: You write it in the query designer..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MS Access requires a `FROM` clause with a table.  So, let's move both to the `FROM` clause.  There are a few other changes as well:

```
select s.sums + p.sump
from (select SUM(Total) as sums
      from Shirt_Mes 
      where CustomerId = 2 and
            Created_Date = #10/5/2016#  -- different date format
     ) as s,  -- Oh, it hurts that MS Access does not have `cross join`
     (select SUM(Total) as sump
      from Pant_Mes 
      where CustomerId = 2 and
            Created_Date = #10/5/2016#
     ) as p;
```